# How would i go about finding Rl when rl is r3

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, theory, thevenin, ohms-law

[image: How would i go about finding Rl :/ I'm so lost]

How would i go about finding Rl :/ I'm so lost iv looked for examples and all they have done is confuse me

Comment: Why are you trying to find RL, when the text of the problem gives you the range of values for RL?  Also, what is is R3?  It's not mentioned in the text of the problem or the schematic.  [Keep in mind that EE.SE is not here to do your homework for you.  You haven't demonstrated sufficient effort for solving the problem.  Being confused is not sufficient.]

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to solve with superposition theorem combined with Thévenin.

- First remove the R<sub>L</sub>
- Then momentarily replace the right voltage source with a short and calculate the voltage at the node where R<sub>L</sub> was attached (voltage divider).
- Next momentarily replace the left voltage source with a short and calculate the voltage at the node where R<sub>L</sub> was attached.
- Superposition theorem says you can add both voltages found for that node to find the actual node voltage (V<sub>TH</sub>).

At this point you probably already know the answer to the current that will flow through R<sub>L</sub> whatever value it has, but let's finish the Thévenin question.

- With R<sub>L</sub> still removed, short both the voltage sources and calculate the resistance you see when you look into the circuit from the R<sub>L</sub> nodes.
- Now you have R<sub>TH</sub> and V<sub>TH</sub>.

For Norton you replace the voltage source and its series resistance, with a current source and a parallel resistance. It's home work, your turn.